# How to validate if a SharePoint library choice column is empty or not using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jquery, jsom

For one of the requirements, I am working with SharePoint online and part of that, I would like to check if a choice column is empty or not using JSOM. Can someone please help me with the code. If a choice column is empty then I would like to restrict the user to perform Save/Upload in a SharePoint document library and show some message that user needs to fill out these fields. There are about 3 choice columns which I would like to validate if they are empty or not.Only and only if all three of them are non- empty then user can do upload or save in a document library. So this code will be added to the edit form of a Sp library.

I have 3 content types in the library, out of which one of those have these three columns so I would want to make sure that validation check only occurs for these 3 columns that are part of a content type, let's say test.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use PreSaveAction function to validate the item.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       ProducerReferral();
       attachEventHandlers(); // function for checking the duplication of files  
       $('input[value=Save]').click(function() {
           PreSaveTest();
       });
   });

   function PreSaveTest() {
       PreSaveAction();
   }

   function PreSaveAction() {
       if ($("#idAttachmentsRow").css("display") == "none") {
           $("#part1 > h4")[1].innerHTML += "<span style='margin-left: 40px;' class='ms-formvalidation ms-csrformvalidation'>Please Attach Files.</span>";
           returnVal = false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }
   }
```

Or

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
 function PreSaveAction() { 
   alert("here");
   var txtStatus = $j(":input[title='Status']").val(); 
   if(txtStatus == "In Progress"){        
   alert("Invalid Status");        
   var statusfocus = $j(":input[title='Status']");        
   statusfocus .focus();        
   return false;}
   return true;
  }
</script>
```

Refer [PreSaveAction](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38255.use-of-presaveaction-function-on-list-forms-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

All the best !!!!

Comment: Hello Shridhar, i can not make them required  since I want the other functionality to work and it depends on columns being non-mandatory and which is why I need to know what would be the JS approach, thanks.

Comment: Hi mdevm, you can use PreSaveAction for choice column validation